# AWS Cloudformation: Give Cloudwatch * Permissions to invoke Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

This is what I am trying to do:

`LambdaInvokePermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
       --snip--
       SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:events:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:rule/*-${Environment}`

However it seems to dislike the * syntax.

I have tried just `SourceArn: !Sub arn:aws:events:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:rule/*` and `SourceArn: '*'` but these also give failure messages like

`The rule * could not be found.`

Does anyone know the correct syntax for this?

Comment: Also tried: arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456789012:* (per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)

My finding is that the only working solution was to omit SourceArn and SourceAccount references for now

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the exact name of the cloudwatch rule that will trigger this lambda function.
Example: arn:aws:events:us-east-1:123456789012:rule/**my-scheduled-rule**.

The SourceArn property of AWS::Lambda::Permission expects a String value: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html#cfn-lambda-permission-sourcearn.
You cannot have multiple cloudwatch rules as the SourceArn(not a list) in a single *AWS::Lambda::Permission* block with a wildcard '*'. To have multiple cloudwatch rules trigger the same lambda function, you will need to add another AWS::Lambda::Permission block in your cloudformation template.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the explanation. I understand this but was hoping to get a wildcard to work.

The problem with specifying the exact name is that as new rules are added that invoke the Lambda, its policy will grow until eventually it hits a size limit (around 60-80 rules). 

My working code right now simply omits the SourceArn property entirely, giving blanket access to CWE. This is not a preferred solution due to concerns over such wide access.

Lastly, your point about the quotes is not correct. !Sub is working fine with pseudo param. Thank you for the reply and the solid explanation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the !Sub function part. I have edited the answer.